# Approximation of a sum for large $n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, riemann-sum

May I know how I can approximate the following sum for large $n$:

$$\frac{1}{n^2 xy}\left[\sum_{i=0}^{nx}\sum_{j=0}^{ny}\frac{1}{1 + \left(\frac{ |i-j|\wedge (n-|i-j|)}{n}\right)^2}\right]$$

where $0 \le x < y \le 1$, such that $nx,ny$ are integers and $\wedge$ is the min function i.e. $a\wedge b = \min\{a,b\}$? I think I should get an integral approximation but is not occurring to me right now. Thanks.

Comment: How is your sum even necessarily defined? With $x,y \in [0,1]$, there's no guarantee that $nx,ny$ (the upper bounds) are even integers...

Comment: @EeveeTrainer The context of the question assumes $nx,ny$ are integers.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a closed-form or an approximation, but was able to make it into $3$ single sums instead. The objective is to find the following:

$$\frac{1}{n^2 xy}\left[\sum_{i=0}^{nx}\sum_{j=0}^{ny}\frac{1}{1 + \left(\frac{ |i-j|\wedge (n-|i-j|)}{n}\right)^2}\right]$$

By splitting this into $i-j < 0$ and $i-j > 0$, we get

$$\frac{1}{n^2 xy}\left[{\sum_{i=0}^{nx}\sum_{j=0}^{i}\frac{1}{1 + \left(\frac{ (i-j)\wedge (n-i+j)}{n}\right)^2}}+\sum_{i=0}^{nx}\sum_{j=i+1}^{ny}\frac{1}{1 + \left(\frac{ (j-i)\wedge (n-j+i)}{n}\right)^2}\right]$$

Then since $i-0 = i, i-1 = i-1..., i-(i) = 0$ ranges from $0$ to $i$ also, the first sum can be rewritten. Also the second sum is reindexed so that it goes over the difference.

$$\frac{1}{n^2 xy}\left[\sum_{i=0}^{nx}\sum_{d=0}^{i}\frac{1}{1 + \left(\frac{ (d)\wedge (n-d)}{n}\right)^2}+\sum_{i=0}^{nx}\sum_{d=1}^{ny-i}\frac{1}{1 + \left(\frac{ (d)\wedge (n-d)}{n}\right)^2}\right]$$

Finally, the frequency of each difference is found

$$\frac{1}{n^2 xy}\left[\sum_{d=0}^{nx}\frac{nx+1-d}{1 + \left(\frac{ (d)\wedge (n-d)}{n}\right)^2}+\sum_{d=1}^{ny-nx} \frac{nx+1}{1 + \left(\frac{ (d)\wedge (n-d)}{n}\right)^2} + \sum_{d = ny-nx+1}^{ny} \frac{ny+1-d}{1 + \left(\frac{ (d)\wedge (n-d)}{n}\right)^2}\right]$$

That brings it from one double sum to three single sums.